# Authentication mechanisms for an application

Tags: authentication, ldap, kerberos, ntlm

What are the best practices if I want my application to authenticate itself to other services?

Let's say I want my application (the programming language doesn't matter) to access a file share or a repository but I don't want to ask the user for password. In addition, I don't want to store passwords in the code of my application. What else can I do? Till now I found only 2,5 options:

1.use Integrated Windows Authentication - but this will, obviously, work on windows only

2.use client certificates and let the service verify them before allowing access

3.use LDAP/RADIUS/CAS with client certificates

is there something else?

Comment: I did ask on stackoverflow but they redirected me here: "this is off-topic for SO, belongs on serverfault.com"

Comment: The answer depends entirely on the business requirements for the application. This isn't something we can help you decide.

Comment: Actually I'm just looking for options. The reason for my question is that I cannot find more than these three.

Answer (score 0):

There is always good old [Kerberos](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/). A little old and stuffy but probably a very interesting contender for what you are trying to do.

Comment: how could I use kerberos without asking the user for password? (besides using Windows Authentication)

Comment: You do have user credentials from the time s/he accessed his/her desktop and you could use Kerberos to implement a single sign-on process (Windows already comes with it, any UNIX/Linux system can be retrofitted). As Michael Hampton mentioned what you are trying to do should be a piece of a bigger picture.

Comment: Of course, but as I said, I'm only looking for possibilities right now. Kerberos however, does reqire the user to enter the passwort at least once somewhen, right?